# LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8) newaliases: In sSMTP aliases are read from a plain text file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

While I am running build for CentOS based docker
I am receiving following warnings

```
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
newaliases: In sSMTP aliases are read from a plain text file


/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
  Updating   : boost-regex-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64                         127/295
  Updating   : yum-plugin-ovl-1.1.31-54.el7_8.noarch                    128/295
  Updating   : yum-utils-1.1.31-54.el7_8.noarch                         129/295
  Updating   : git-review-1.28.0-1.el7.noarch                           130/295
  Updating   : passwd-0.79-6.el7.x86_64                                 131/295
  Updating   : gtk-update-icon-cache-3.22.30-6.el7.x86_64               132/295
  Updating   : libcroco-0.6.12-6.el7_9.x86_64                           133/295
  Updating   : 1:openssl-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.x86_64                         134/295
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
  Updating   : ccache-3.7.7-1.el7.x86_64                                135/295
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
  Updating   : libssh2-1.8.0-4.el7.x86_64                               136/295
  Updating   : 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7_9.1.x86_64                  137/295
  Updating   : libarchive-3.1.2-14.el7_7.x86_64                         138/295
```

Previously version of the same Docker had no such warning, the only delta is additional yup package  autoconf

The Dockerfile looks like that

```
COPY yum_requirements.txt yum_requirements.txt
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install $(cat yum_requirements.txt) \
&& yum clean all \
&& rm -rf /var/tmp/yum-*
```

yum_requirements.txt contains list of packages

I tried to run localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8; exit 0 but it doesn't help

Also while trying to run any command inside the docker receiving following warning

```
 autoreconf
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding ENV LC_ALL=C  to Dockerfile solving the issue